# Finding Ramana Maharishi's saying

Tags: ramana-maharshi

Quite a while ago, I read somewhere that Ramana Maharishi said

*only gyani (self realized person) can understand the gyani ( Self realized person).No one else can understand.*

Well, I cannot find the exact sentence and I have been looking for this for days. Can someone guide me in the right way?

Did Bhagwan really said something relevant to this?

I am aware that this is not the right place to ask such a question but I cannot really find any other place where I can look for the answer.